# Change properties of a bootstrap button conditionally

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have a bootstrap dropdown button that I wish to disable if two ids meet. This is what the button currently looks like.

```
<>
                                <DropdownButton
                                    title={fixtureDetails.homeTeam?.abbreviation + " End"}
                                    variant="outline-primary"
                                    className="ml-2"
                                    size="sm"
                                    disabled
                                >
```

This is what i'm trying to achieve;

```
<>
                                    <DropdownButton
                                        title={fixtureDetails.homeTeam?.abbreviation + " End"}
                                        variant="outline-primary"
                                        className="ml-2"
                                        size="sm"
                                       { previousTeamId() == homeTeam ? disabled : "" }
                                        >
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you could do something like this

```
<DropdownButton
        title={fixtureDetails.homeTeam?.abbreviation + " End"}
        variant="outline-primary"
        className="ml-2"
        size="sm"
        isDisabled ={ previousTeamId() == homeTeam ? true : false}
      />
```

**and then bind that props with your button component to disabled it.**

```
<button disabled={PaymentResponse.isDisabled}>
        Check
      </button>
```